# Can't mount LaCie d2 SAFE in OS X 10.9.5

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, lacie

I have a LaCie d2 SAFE 1TB I got in 2010 to 2011. It worked fine on an older version of a OS X but once I updated to 10.9.5 it stopped. Seems LaCie has not updated the drivers since 2009. Tried all the basics but a clean 10.9 just does not work with the drivers. It shows up in the USB correctly as "d2 safe" but the LaCie SAFE app does not detect it and I can't unlock it.

At this point I may to have to wipe my Mac and restore to 10.7, buy a new drive, copy it off, then update again. Has anyone found a better workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your LaCie's SATA to USB/FireWire bridge has a proprietary password protection mechanism. Probably not full disk encryption, but just a password lock that keeps the bridge chip from allowing the drive to be mounted without successful password authentication first. Since LaCie hasn't kept their proprietary software up to date to run on modern versions of OS X, you can't tell the bridge to let your Mac mount the drive.

If you have access to a Mac that's still running an earlier version of OS X where the LaCie software works, or if you can temporarily boot your Mac from such a version of OS X (perhaps off of a USB flash drive or other external hard drive, DVD-ROM, or some other partition), then you can probably enter the password once and then disable the password protection mechanism.

After that, you should be able to use the hard drive as just a generic external hard drive on any system. You just won't be able to (nor want to) enable the password lock again.

A friend of mine had basically this same problem with a WD My Book drive, and that was the fix for him. I'll bet your LaCie situation is similar.

Comment: The drive is encrypted, you need the app to run the fingerprint scanner that sets the key and unlocks and mounts the drive. I dont have a second mac to use, thou i guess I can look into a "live" usb version. But I think i have to back to 10.6 or 10.7 so thats prob not going to work out. I will prob have to just reinstall the old version and copy to a new drive. End of me using lacie again.

Comment: @RyanMills Here's a driver from 2012 with 10.8 compatibility. Have you tried it in 10.9? https://www.lacie.com/us/support/drivers/driver.htm?id=10194

Comment: @RyanMills Upon further review, that link I posted looks like it's for the "Rugged" version of the SAFE only. But it probably couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: Yes, i did just for the heck of it, no change.